# SSRS print preview prints on many pages

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Im building out an SSRS report for a client and when i build it, seems to be fine. when I print or do a printer preview however, the report and its contents are being printed over 4 pages rather than all on one page. I could use some help as I dont deal with SSRS that much.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the designer you should open the **Document Outline** view. The basic structure for a report is something along these lines:

```
Report
    -> Body
        -> Control / tablix / subreport 1
        -> Control / tablix / subreport 2
        -> etc
    -> Page Header
    -> Page Footer
```

If you select the **Report** item, the properties pane will show you several important properties:

- Page Size (for printing and pdf renderer)
- Interactive Size (for other renderers)
- Margins

These properties determine on what sizes the report should be printed. If you select the **Body** item, you will also see a `Size` property. That size could grow, depending on your tablixes, because they may expand horizontally and vertically.

Basically if your body size is larger than the Page Size (and margins) allow for, the printer will render additional pages. You should play around with those values to fix your issues, I'd think. Looking at your example screens you could start with:

- decreasing the margins
- changing the page size so it becomes landscape
- play around with positioning in the body to fit more content on a page